# SQL injection possible in this query

Tags: mysql, session

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_badges (user_id, badge_id) 
VALUES ('". $_SESSION['user']['id'] ."',VIP)");
```

How can I make this safe?

Comment: Anyone know something about this?

Comment: Yes, it absolutely is. Use *Prepared Statements*

Comment: Use prepared statement instead to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use newer functions like `mysqli_query` or even better `PDO library`.
2. Bind params, do not inject them in query.
3. Sanitize your params.

Read:

[About PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), [About MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), [About sanitizing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).

Comment: @IbraDigga . . . Probably not.  mysql_ is no longer supported.  The correct option is to switch to mysqli.  If you want security, then use supported software.